# Powershell command to find replace not giving any error, but not replacing

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

**What I am trying to do:**

Read a .config file content as Raw string with powershell and find particular string and replacing with desired string

**The line I am trying to find and replace:**

```
<add key="ReportServerUrl" value="http://SQL14\SQL2016_INS1/ReportServer"></add>
```

**Replace the above line with:**

```
<add key="ReportServerUrl" value="http://SQL14/SQL2016_INS1/ReportServer"></add>
```

**Powershell command that I tried:**

```
(Get-Content "C:\target\Server.config" -Raw).Replace("SQL14\\SQL2016_INS1/ReportServer","SQL14/SQL2016_INS1/ReportServer") | Set-Content C:\target\Server.config;
```

**Problem:**

the above statement executes without any error but above not replacing the string as intended

Please help

**Update 1:**

Tried with whole line replacement

```
 (Get-Content "C:\target\Server.config" -Raw).Replace('<add key="ReportServerUrl" value="http://SQL14\SQL2016_INS1/ReportServer"></add>
','<add key="ReportServerUrl" value="http://SQL14/SQL2016_INS1/ReportServer"></add>
') | Set-Content C:\target\Server.config;
```

this also executes with out erros, but no replacement done.

Comment: Why do you have \\ in your replace? Just use a single \.

Comment: to escape \ there

Comment: `.Replace()` method does verbatim string/char replacements. Escapes are not needed.

Comment: ok thanks let me try

Comment: No luck buddy. if tried removed that extra \ it didnt work, then i tried Update 1 code in my above post...that also not working

Comment: can you please tell me if the code that I tried part of Update 1 in above post is wrong ?

Comment: Your target string and replacement string are the same in your Update 1 example.

Comment: My bad..let me check

Comment: Now its works, so just wanted to know what ever string i need to include in Replace function should be ' ' or " " right ?

Comment: It depends. If there are no variables in the string and no other single quotes in the string, then single quotes is generally best. If you have embedded quotes that match the outer quotes, then you have to escape them, which is a PowerShell thing rather than a `.Replace()` thing.

Comment: Hi i have another example is this correct? `Replace('binding name="wsHTTPPartyBindingConfig"','binding name="WSHttpBinding_PartyService"')`